# jest, typescript and "ReferenceError: AudioBuffer is not defined"

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, jestjs

I use jest and the lib tonejs on my project.

I can launch the test manuelly without issue, but when I launch it passing by the IDE ( Intellij, in order to debug) I have this error:

"ReferenceError: AudioBuffer is not defined"

For the record, I use a lib who use AudioBuffer, but not
I see that AudioBuffer is a class defined in node_module/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts. Any idea why jest-intellij can't go to it?

Edit : the launch line:
npx jest config=jest.config.js --runTestsByPath $PROJECT_PATH/src/character-form.component.spec.ts

My test.spec.json:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jest",
      "node",
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "strictNullChecks": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "dist/**/*",
   "node_modules/**/*"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.e2e-spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts",
    "node_modules/typescript/**/*"
  ]
}
```

a part of my angular.json:

```
 "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:jest",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "config": "jest.config.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
```

my tsconfig.spec.json:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jest",
      "node",
      "webpack-env"
    ]
  }
}
```

my tsconfig:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "rootDir": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitThis": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "dist/**/*",
    "node_modules/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: This is runtime error and it has nothing to do with lib.dom.d.ts, that you have `dom` lib enabled only cheats TS to think that AudioBuffer is available. It's unknown why it works outside IDE because AudioBuffer is not provided by JSDOM afaik, I'd expect it to fail any way. How do you expected it to work in Node btw? Mock it, or mock third-party lib that uses it.

Comment: How can I mock-it? the error append during an import

Comment: what command do you use to run tests manually? please provide screenshots of the console with the command and the output, both when running from the IDE and outside it

Comment: @lena npx jest config=jest.config.js --runTestsByPath /Users/sarahbuisson/dev/workspace-perso/labyrinth-game/website/src/app/characterEditor/character-form/character-form.component.spec.ts

Comment: and what does your run configuration in the IDE look like? please provide screenshots of the console with the command and the output, both when running from the IDE and outside it